# Customizing android`s listView elements pragmatically

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to add some custom effects to some `ListView``s items. Noting very fancy only some subtitles, custom color on selection or even changing a text value of the item.

Currently I am generating my `ListView` like so:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
String[] values = new String[] { "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };
ArrayAdapter<String> files = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
listView.setAdapter(files);
```

What should I do to add subtitles for list items? Or add some action to a specific item?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like creating adapters like that, it doesn't give any transparency into what's happening or much control over the views, I prefer extending a BaseAdapter to use with a ListView

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Object> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        //set view values, etc
        return view;
    }
}
```

Using this you get better control over the ListView and its cells, there are many tutorials out there, search for'custom listview' and you should find something that will help